# Django updating model with composite primary keys

Tags: python, django

I am trying to update a model, with two primary keys.

Since django is not officially supporting it, I am using the workaround:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('key1', 'key2'),)

    key1= models.IntegerField(blank=False, primary_key=True)
    key2= models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=30)
    attr3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attr4 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

But whenever I try to update an existing object I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: myApp_myModell.key1, myApp_myModel.key2
```

I tried the following to update my model:

```
myModel.objects.update_or_create(
    key1=kw1, 
    key2= kw2,
    defaults={
    'attr3':attr3_str,
    'attr4':attr4_str,
    })
```

and the following:

```
defaults={
    'attr3':attr3_str
    'attr4':attr4_str,
    }
try:
    obj = myModel.objects.get(key1=kw1, key2=kw2)
    for key, value in defaults:
        settatr(obj, key, value)
    obj.save()
except myModel.DoesNotExist:
    print("DOESNT EXISIT")
    new_values = {'key1': kw1, 'key2': kw2}
    new_values.update(defaults)
    obj = myModel(**new_values)
    obj.save()
```

Any ideas how I can update my model without getting an integrity error?

Comment: have you run migrations after adding `unique_together` constraint?

Comment: Yes I did, I also did reset my database with
manage.py flush -> manage.py makemigrations -> manage.py migrate

Comment: what are values of kw1 and kw2 variables?

Comment: kw1 is an integer (1) and kw2 is a string with 9 characters (roundname)

Comment: Using second way doest it print `DOESNT EXISIT` ?

Comment: No, it fails at the first obj.save() call

Comment: have you proved, that `kw1` and `kw2` are __definitely__ not `None` inside of the except block?

Comment: @dahrens the program breaks before getting to the except block at the first obj.save().

Comment: naah... something is fishy here. If it doesn't got to except block it means there is a record in db with `key1=kw1` and `key2=kw2`. Do you mind checking `print myModel.objects.filter(key1=kw1, key2=kw2).count()` in the beginning of `try` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what causes the real issue, but removing the `blank=False` and `primary_key=True` in my model worked for me:

```
class myModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('key1', 'key2'),)

    key1= models.IntegerField()
    key2= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attr3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    attr4 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

with

```
defaults={
    'attr3':attr3_str
    'attr4':attr4_str,
    }
try:
    obj = myModel.objects.get(key1=kw1, key2=kw2)
    for key, value in defaults:
        setattr(obj, key, value)
    obj.save()
except myModel.DoesNotExist:
    new_values = {'key1': kw1, 'key2': kw2}
    new_values.update(defaults)
    obj = myModel(**new_values)
    obj.save()
```

Thank you for your help!